# Плавная прокрутка ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте! Чтобы понять мой вопрос, стоит вспомнить 2D игры. У нас есть главный герой, который бороздит просторы карты, фактически всегда оставаясь в центре экрана. В качестве главного героя у меня - картинка. На стрелочках у меня стоит передвижение. Фактически, это анимация, меняющая координаты изображения на Canvas'е. Я научился двигать ScrollViewer одновременно с героем с помощью *svBar.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(svBar.ContentHorizontalOffset - 100)*
Однако, это происходит дерганно, а хотелось бы плавно.
Вариант, пусть игрок двигает Скроллбар сам, по-моему не очень хороший.

Так же, готов рассмотреть другие варианты выхода из данной ситуации.

Comment: А зачем Scrollbar? Почему не RenderTransform (или LayoutTransform)? И почему всегда на 100, а не на величину реального смещения?

Comment: Хм, можно более подробно описать идею?
100 просто число, которые для меня удобно перемещало экран.

Comment: Ну, каждый раз, когда игрок перемещается в силу динамики игры, устанавливать смещение в (размер экрана/2 - позиция игрока).

Comment: Так, я разобрался со смещением с помощью RenderTransform и TranslateTransform. А как лучше всего сделать перемещение игрока параллельно с перемещением экрана? При условии, что игрок передвигается небольшими анимированными отрезками(если зажать клаавишу движения в моем случае будет экран неприятно дергаться).

Comment: В общем, я решил этот вопрос написав анимацию для TranslateTransform 

var a = new DoubleAnimation();
a.To = offset  - 100;
offset -= 100;
a.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25);
                cnField.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, a);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что Scrollbar не лучшая для этого идея) Но тем не менее, лучше передвигать не на 100 сразу,а частями. Например, так:

пусть PosX это положение текущее ползунка, NeedX - то, в которое он должен попасть. Vx - скорость передвижения, тогда:

```
 if ( (NeedX - PosX) > eps ){
   PosX += Vx;
} else if ( (PosX -  NeedX) > eps){
   PosX -= Vx;
}
```

Это в все проверять по таймеру) 
Но, ИМХО, лучше  добавить вместо Vx, Vx*dt? где dt - разница времени между кадрами, и обновлять каждый кадр)

Надеюсь ход моей мысли ясен)

Comment: Такой вариант рассматривался, да, однако я боюсь плодить лишние таймеры. Анимация, просто, работает в своём, видимо, отдельном потоке, что позволяет запускать несколько сразу. Однако, все равно спасибо!